# Java - Start a process -exactly- like windows7 would do it

Tags: java, process, exec

I'm trying to start a process within a testing framework which is written in Java, but the process is acting somehow different. The "log in" button freezes. The problem can be 
fixed by closing the testing framework which started the process

There is -NO- problem when the process is started by the user. 
(via explorer, visual studio, cmdline && DURING runtime of testing framework)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.directory(workingDirectory);
```

and

```
process = runtime.exec(commands, null, workingDirectory);
```

fail to deliver proper results. The behavior of the process is still different to a process which would be created with a double click on the application icon. the application is written in native c++

How do I start a process -exactly- like Windows7 would do it?

Comment: Does the C++ program produce any console output?

Comment: When you click the icon, a lot of things can happen: working directory is set, command line parameters are passed and so on. Are you doing all these things?

Comment: I will check for console output (I guess cmdline no, but Visual Studio logs about 10k lines - I'll verify later) - @biziclop - commandline parameters are the same, WD is set to directory where file is located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to read the process streams in order to resolve blocking issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be the null in your .exec command.  That's the environment variables you want to pass along.

Check out the javadocs for the java.lang.Runtime class:

envp - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process.

Perhaps you're missing an environment variable or something when running your java program.

Comment: can you supply an example on how to retrieve the current env settings and how to pass them?